# “EasyScreenOCR” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I have just downloaded an application but whenever try to open it, faced error popUp & unable to understand.

**Error Screenshot:**

[image]

**Properties of my mac:**

[image]

Comment: Right-click the .app and choose "Open" from the context menu

Answer (score 0):

All APP that not be downloaded from AppStore has this alert. Do not worry about it. You can go to Apple menu > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click General. and enable Mac to open EasyScreenOCR

[enable app not come from AppStore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HSjp.png)

Comment: [System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhuYd.png) where is  EasyScreenOCR enable option

Comment: You can see the image in the answer

Comment: Then, I think you can download EasyScreenOCR from the Appstore. You can search the name there.

Comment: Okay , Thank. you

Answer (score 0):

**"adb" can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.
This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information**

Solution: System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> click "Open Anyway"

[image]

[image]